# trigger popup when returning to site

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to think of how to trigger a popup message when a person re-enters the site due to clicking on PayPal's 'Cancel and return to thatsite.com'.

In the PHP/Jquery shopping cart script being used, here's the line that sends them back to a specific spot on the site:

```
'&cancel_return='.$config['woowp'].'#order-cancelled/'.$ppl;
```

There must be a simple way for me to trigger a popup w/jquery, as in (pseudo-code):

```
IF hash/url = www.site.com/#order-cancelled
THEN fadeIn('slow') div#popup;
```

I'd like it so that this particular URL has a popup associated with it. In other words, when they click 'cancel and return to thatsite.com', they'll be taken to www.thatsite.com/#order-cancelled, and a couple seconds later a popup shows up.

I can handle the markup for the popup div, but how to trigger it? (Hopefully with jquery, as I'm utterly useless with PHP.) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (window.location.hash == '#order-cancelled') {
   setTimeout(function () { $("#popup").show(); }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `window.location.hash` in javascript and check if it equal to `#order-cancelled`